# Rotate cube about fixed axis

Tags: python, 3d, rotational-matrices, vpython

So I have a code that takes in real time angle information from an IMU sensor in Raspberry Pi, which is transmitted to my computer using mqtt broker. The angle is based on the orientation of the IMU during upright position (i.e. fixed coordinate system). Now I want to animate the IMU by taking the difference between two corresponding sensor readings which would indicate the amount of rotation required in that particular axis. However, the animation I get is not displaying the orientation correctly. My question is, in the

```
obj.rotate(angle=a, axis=vec(x,y,z),origin=vector(x0,y0,z0))
```

function of vpython, how do I say such that the rotation is about the fixed coordinate system, instead of rotating around the IMU's axis? My code is below:

```
from vpython import *
import math
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import time

scene.title = "VPython: Draw a rotating cube"

scene.range = 2
scene.autocenter = True

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    global callback_on_connect
    print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))

    # Subscribing in on_connect() - if we lose the connection and
    # reconnect then subscriptions will be renewed.
    client.subscribe("CoreElectronics/test")#these two are topics; thus the client here listens to these two topics
    client.subscribe("CoreElectronics/topic")
    callback_on_connect=1

# The callback for when a PUBLISH message is received from the server.
#  ONLY WORKS IF YOU HAVE A MESSAGE FROM RASPBERRY PI SINCE IT IS A CALLBACK!
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    global yaw
    global pitch
    global roll
    global callback_on_message
    callback_on_message=1
    #print(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.payload))
    #print(float(msg.payload))
    #print(3)
    f=msg.payload
    angles = [float(i) for i in f.split()]
    #print(3)
    #type(angles)

    yaw=angles[0]
    pitch=angles[1]
    roll=angles[2]
    print(angles)
    #x = [float(i) for i in f.split()]
    #print(x[0])
    #print(x[1])
        # Do something else

print("Drag with right mousebutton to rotate view.")
print("Drag up+down with middle mousebutton to zoom.")

cube = box(pos=vec(0,0,0),length=1,height=0.1,width=1)    # using defaults, see http://www.vpython.org/contents/docs/defaults.html

client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message

print("Connecting to server...")
client.connect("mqtt.eclipse.org", 1883, 60)
print("Reached loop function...")
client.loop_start()

yaw=''
pitch=''
roll=''
yaw2=0
pitch2=0
roll2=0
#callback_on_connect=0
callback_on_message=0;

while callback_on_message==0:
    print("waiting for callback as a result of successful message receive", callback_on_message)
#now we are connected, can start taking in data
while True:      # Animation-loop
    try:
        #print("animating")
        #arrow(pos=vec(0,0,0),axis=vec(1,0,0))
        #arrow(pos=vec(0,0,0),axis=vec(0,1,0))
        #arrow(pos=vec(0,0,0),axis=vec(0,0,1))
        cube.rotate(angle=radians(yaw-yaw2), axis=vec(1,0,0),origin=vector(0,0,0))
        cube.rotate(angle=radians(pitch-pitch2), axis=vec(0,1,0),origin=vector(0,0,0))
        cube.rotate(angle=radians(roll-roll2), axis=vec(0,0,1),origin=vector(0,0,0))
        yaw2=yaw
        pitch2=pitch
        roll2=roll

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        client.loop_stop()

    #cube.rotate( angle=yaw, axis=vec(1,0,0) )
    #cube.rotate( angle=pitch, axis=vec(0,1,0) )
    #cube.rotate( angle=roll, axis=vec(0,0,1) )
```

Comment: I don't think I understand the question. Obviously obj.rotate() uses the VPython coordinate system and knows nothing about IMU.

Comment: A suggestion: For VPython questions it's better to post to the VPython forum, where there are many more VPython users who will see your question than if you post to stackoverflow:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups&hl=en#!forum/vpython-users